# Django-Registration: adding login and registration capabilities to every page

Tags: django-registration

I just got done integrating django-registration==0.8  into my project (Django==1.3, Python==2.7) and would now like to add login and registration capabilities to all pages rather than just to /login and /register. Can anyone suggest a clean way to do this without altering django-registration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I m actually trying to solve the same problem and found this. Hope it helps.
http://www.nerdydork.com/django-login-form-on-every-page.html

Answer (score 0):

This seems overly complicated, why not just add a login form in your base.html (the same that you have in your  login.html template) and have the form's action set to {% url "auth_login" %} ?
I did that, it worked well, and redirects the user to the regular login view if the authentication failed.